# How can I reroute the training input pipeline to test pipeline in tensorflow using tf.contrib.graph_editor?

Tags: tensorflow

Suppose now I have a training input pipeline which finally generate `train_x` and `train_y` using `tf.train.shuffle_batch`. I export meta graph and re-import the graph in another code file. Now I want to detach the input pipeline, i.e., the `train_x` and `train_y`, and connect a new `test_x` and `test_y`. How can I make accomplish this using  tf.contrib.graph_editor?

**EDIT:** As suggested by @iga, I change my input directory using `input_map`

```
filenames = tf.train.match_filenames_once(FLAGS.data_dir + '*', name='matching_filenames')
if FLAGS.ckpt != '':
    latest = FLAGS.log_dir + FLAGS.ckpt
else:
    latest = tf.train.latest_checkpoint(FLAGS.log_dir)
if not latest or not os.path.exists(latest+'.meta'):
    print("checkpoint " + latest + " does not exist")
    sys.exit(1)
saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(latest+'.meta', 
                                   input_map={'matching_filenames:0':filenames},
                                   import_scope='import')
g = tf.get_default_graph()
```

but I get the following error:

> ValueError: graph_def is invalid at node u'matching_filenames/Assign':
>   Input tensor 'matching_filenames:0' Cannot convert a tensor of type
>   string to an input of type string_ref.
>   Are there any elegant way to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

For this task, you should be able to just use `input_map` argument to https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/import_graph_def. If you are using [import_meta_graph](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/import_meta_graph), you can pass the input_map into its `kwargs` and it will get passed down to import_graph_def.

**RESPONSE TO EDIT**: I am assuming that your original graph (the one you are deserializing) had the same `matching_filenames` variable. Quite confusingly, the tensor name "matching_filenames:0" actually refers to the tensor going from the `VariableV2` op to the `Assign` op. The type of this edge is `string_ref` and you don't really want to break that edge.

The output from a variable typically goes through an identity op called `matching_filenames/read`. This is what you want to use as the key in your input_map. For the value, you want the same tensor in your new `filenames`. So, your call should probably look like:

```
tf.train.import_meta_graph(latest+'.meta', 
                           input_map={'matching_filenames/read': filenames.read_value()},
                           import_scope='import')
```

In general, variables are fairly complicated. If this does not work, you can use some placeholder op and feed the names into it manually.

Comment: I follow your advice but I got another error, please see my edited question, thanks